# What happens when a file is being moved/copied to another location at the same hard drive?

Tags: memory-management, memory-hardware

I've got a few questions about how hard-drives works with information that I haven't been able to find the answers to anywhere, so I figured I'd give this a shot instead. I know the basics on how computers store/retrieve data from the disks, but I've got a few other questions that I'm not so sure about.

Firstly, *What happens when you move a file from one map to another (via the file explorer)?*

Does the computer look at the FAT-table to see where the data is stored, and then use the table to store the data in the new map?

*Secondly, What happens when you copy a file from one map to another?*

Thanks in advance.